# table design for storing large number of rows

Tags: database-design, postgresql

I am trying to store in a postgresql database some unique identifiers along with the site they have been seen on. I can't really decide which of the following 3 option to choose in order to be faster and easy maintainable. The table would have to provide the following information:

- the unique identifier which unfortunately it's text
- the sites on which that unique identifier has been seen

The amount of data that would have to hold is rather large: there are around 22 millions unique identifiers that I know of.

So I thought about the following designs of the table:

- id - integer

  identifier - text

  seen_on_site - an integer, foreign key to a sites table

This approach would require around 22 mil multiplied by the number of sites.

- id - integer

  identifier - text

  seen_on_site_1 - boolean

  seen_on_site_2 - boolean

  ............

  seen_on_site_n - boolean

Hopefully the number of sites won't go past 10. This would require only the number of unique identifiers that I know of, that is around 20 millions, but it would make it hard to work with it from an ORM perspective.

- one table that would store only unique identifiers, like in:

id - integer

unique_identifier - text,

one table that would store only sites, like in:

id - integer

site - text

and one many to many relation, like:

id - integer,

unique_id - integer (fk to the table storing identifiers)

site_id - integer (fk to sites table)

- another approach would be to have a table that stores unique identifiers for each site

So, which one seems like a better approach to take on the long run?

Answer (score 1):

Have two tables.
Table 1 
Site ID,Site Name, Site Description
Site ID -> Primary Key
Site Name -> Index

Table 2 would be the one you are talking about.
Row ID, Site ID, Whatever Info.
Row ID -> Primary Key
Site ID -> Foreign Key into table 1
Index (Row Id, Site ID)

Comment: Ok, but this would mean that I'll have to store 22 millions unique data multiplied by the number of sites I have. Is this feasible? I am not very good at database design, yet :). Thanks!

Comment: @hyperboreean That is not a problem as long as you only access through the indexes or primary keys.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a natural text-based unique identifier for site (url, perhaps?), then the only thing you need is ONE table with two fields:

```
CREATE TABLE (
    unique_identifier TEXT NOT NULL,
    site_identifier TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (unique_identifier, site_identifier)
);
```

You could then also add a UNIQUE INDEX on (site_identifier, unique_identifier) to facilitate lookups by site.

You may end up using a little extra space for the main table this way, but it is dead simple to query, update, and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

I'd definitely avoid the ten column boolean horror if I were you, as there will always be more sites later. I'd agree with Romain Hippeau, with the added suggestion that you might want an index on sites to answer questions like 'Who has visited site x?'.